# Two text contents overlay on a UILabel

Tags: ios

I have a label which is subview of a normal `UIView`, not in a `UITableView`/`UITableViewCell`, depend on generated event, the label will be set a corresponding string. But sometimes, after setting new string value for the label, the old one's still there, it makes two strings overlay each other. Since it happens seldomly, I couldn't say how to make it happen, and does the solution I found can fix it or not.

Here is the code for setting the text:

```
messageLabel.text = message
```

Does anyone has any idea what happens to the label? Maybe the label doesn't update it's layout. The result looks like this:

[image]

I did check the [Debugging View Hierarchies](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html) and there is only one label object with the overlay texts like that.
The code for setting text value:

```
func didGenerateEvent(event: AnyObject) {
    if let event = event as? Event {
        switch event.type {
        case .one:
            setContent("This is message of event one.")
        case .two:
            setContent("This is message of event two, but longer.")
        }
    }
}

func setContent(message: String) {
    messageLabel.text = message
}
```

Comment: How did you created your label? Is it a UITableView? Do `NSLog(@"messageLabel: %@", messageLabel)` before you set its text. My guess is that's a whole new object. You can use https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html to verify it also.

Comment: I hope you are not Adding `UILable` Programetically On `Tablecell`

Comment: Please Post some code so that we can see  what u are doing wrong

Comment: Have you checked `clears graphics context` of `UILabel`. Try after checking it

Comment: I have edited the question, the label is subview of a normal UIView, and there is only one object when checking by Debugging View Hierarchies.

Comment: Hi @Bali, "Clear Graphics Context" is already enable.

Comment: Try after unchecking opaque field of `UILabel` in the interface builder

Comment: Also make sure you are not allocating a new `UILabel` to the object `messageLabel`

Comment: It's also uncheck Opaque field already. I only use one label, not create new one, just updating the text.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "Clear Graphics Context" checkbox is enabled. Or set clearsContextBeforeDrawing in code.